# What is the use of the Developer Tools in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you click on Help, I see the item "Toggle Developer Tools".

I just want to ask what is the use of the Developer Tools inside VS Code. I don't see any information in the docs.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

When you select the option *Help > Toggle Developer Tools*, the [Chrome DevTools window](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) should open. Visual Studio Code is built with [Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron), which is simply put a wrapper or container for creating desktop applications built with HTML and Javascript.

With this in mind, the Developer Tools can be especially handy if you're debugging or developing plugins, or IDE specifics for Visual Studio Code itself.

Answer (score 10):

In mycase, can not find in Toggle Developer Tools from Help, but find CommandPalette(Cmd+P and type '>').

Comment: You opening command palette with `cmd + shift + p` and you access files with `cmd + p`. The first one is basically just prefixing by a `>` yeah.