# Why does "Ctrl + R", which is the key bound to "Reload Window" in vscode, doesn't Reload Window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I'm a new user of vscode.

I ran into a problem that I was told would be resolved by "Reload Window".  So I first went through the "Command Palette" to find it, and it did fix my problem.  However, I noticed that it says it is bound to "Ctrl + R".  So if that's the key sequence it's bound to, why does holding down Ctrl and pressing r not execute that function?  It actually brings up the "Select to open" prompt, with the list of recent files as selection choices.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59573038/5730568) could help you understand why the shortcut `Ctrl + R` doesn't work in some cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step

1.VIEW->COMMAND PALETTE->RELOAD WINDOW or <kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>

2. Click the **setting** icon

[image: List item]

3. Right Button -> change when expression->clear all the *text* or *command* and press enter

[image: List item]

4. Now Test the code <kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Total Result Live(Gif):

[image]

**Warning**.
Sometimes <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> already has many bindings.
Consider changing the key binding of "Reload Window".
Or change the key bindings of those other commands.

Comment: _Consider changing the key binding of "Reload Window"._
[Here is an example of doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71439490).

Answer (score 12):

I just tested the sequence:

- "Preferences: Open Key Shortcut" (through the command palette)
- Filter on reload
- right click and select "Change when expression"
- delete the `isdevelopment` value, and type the "Enter" key

From there, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does indeed reload the VSCode window immediately.

Comment: +1 This helped me too... I had manually entered the hyphen `-`, but pressing `Enter` on an empty input is something else that looks like ` -` (space+hyphen), but must store something else.