# VSCode extension is working fine on debugging mode, but not working when published

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

Actually, the extension is about generating starting boilerplate code for react components by right-clicking on the folder and select whether to generate functional or class component, this extension is working fine on debugging, but when published it is not working and not giving me any error, here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-provider",
  "displayName": "React Provider",
  "description": "Generate class and functional React components in just one click",
  "publisher": "Huzaifa-Ahmed",
  "repository": "https://github.com/Huzaifaahmed20/Code-Provider",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.50.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:react-provider.genFuncComp",
    "onCommand:react-provider.genClassComp"
  ],
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "react-provider.genFuncComp",
        "title": "Generate Functional Component"
      },
      {
        "command": "react-provider.genClassComp",
        "title": "Generate Class Component"
      }
    ],
    "menus": {
      "explorer/context": [
        {
          "command": "react-provider.genFuncComp",
          "group": "1_modification",
          "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder"
        },
        {
          "command": "react-provider.genClassComp",
          "group": "1_modification",
          "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.50.0",
    "@types/glob": "^7.1.3",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.7",
    "eslint": "^7.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.1.1",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "mocha": "^8.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2",
    "vscode-test": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.164",
    "@types/mkdirp": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: No, VSCode does show the errors but they are in Developer Tools, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765782/what-is-the-use-of-the-developer-tools-in-vs-code Probably you messed up the dependencies (as dev dependencies are not bundled in the published extension).

Comment: Can you please elaborate this?