# Why would a custom VSCode Extension work in development but not when published?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am stumped. I worked several months developing a language extension for VSCode and it works great in the extension development environment. But when I publish it, it does not function. I have tried everything to no avail.

Any suggestions as to why it wouldn't work specifically when published would be greatly appreciated.

Extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dehilster.nlp

Source code:
https://github.com/VisualText/vscode-nlp

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you be more specific than "it does not work"?

Comment: Not a big deal. Use Developer Tools to see what error message is there, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765782/what-is-the-use-of-the-developer-tools-in-vs-code You probably forgot to pack up something.

Comment: It has all the treeviews icons in the correct places but no controls or menus work at all. It’s like the entire GUI interface to the extension is non functioning.

Comment: Lex: it works fine in the development mode. Could it be the required nodjs packages that are required that could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was a dependency missing (in this case tslib) and I had to add it to the package building directly. For some reason, the tslib being listed as a dependency in the package.json file didn't seem to fix it. So I added the folder node_modules/tslib/**/* to the .vscodeignore file and then it worked. THis is not the way ultimately do this but it works for now.